# Any way to have capitalized words appear in different color?

Tags: interface, notepad++

```
HELLO_I_AM_A_CONSTANT_VARIABLE => 1,
```

Is there any way in Notepad++ to have a word in all caps appear as a different color? If it matters I'm coding in Perl.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Add each capitalized word to the UDL keywords list, as follows:

- Click Language => Define Your Language
- Click `Keywords Lists`
- Add `HELLO_I_AM_A_CONSTANT_VARIABLE` to 1st Group
- Click Styler
- Select the color
- Click OK